# Looping through an array of objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects that I'm attempting to get the genre name value from.  The output to the console is the following.

```
{:genre_name=>"Education", :title_ids=>[]}
{:genre_name=>"Health and Fitness", :title_ids=>[]}
{:genre_name=>"Animals and Nature", :title_ids=>[35, 49, 7, 10, 14, 17, 25, 28, 3283]}
{:genre_name=>"Short Stories", :title_ids=>[]}
{:genre_name=>"Literary Collections", :title_ids=>[]}
{:genre_name=>"Essays", :title_ids=>[]}
```

How do I loop through the array and the objects within it?

Comment: What do you mean specifically? It looks like you *did* loop through the array.

Comment: What you wrote is not an array.

Comment: I mean how do I get the genre_name value once I'm looping through the array?

Comment: `the_item_under_iteration[:genre_name]`, just like any other Ruby hash. But you would appear to have an array of hashes, not an array of objects (yes, I know hashes are objects; you know what I mean).

Comment: The more important question is *why* do you have an array of hashes; if this is Rails, why don't you have an ActiveRecord relation with actual objects in it? And if you're just trying to get the genre names, you should be plucking them.

Comment: I just get 'no implicit conversion of String into Integer'

Comment: I guess I don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4):

```
[
  {:genre_name=>"Education", :title_ids=>[]},
  {:genre_name=>"Health and Fitness", :title_ids=>[]},
  {:genre_name=>"Animals and Nature", :title_ids=>[35, 49, 7, 10, 14, 17, 25, 28, 3283]},
  {:genre_name=>"Short Stories", :title_ids=>[]},
  {:genre_name=>"Literary Collections", :title_ids=>[]},
  {:genre_name=>"Essays", :title_ids=>[]}
].each do |h|
  puts h[:genre_name]
end

#=>
# Education
# Health and Fitness
# Animals and Nature
# Short Stories
# Literary Collections
# Essays
```